# How to print line 6 through 10 after last match?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

After matching the last "Constrained" I want to print the 6th to 10th line:

This is what I've tried:

```
awk '/Constrained/ { print ; for(n=6; n<10; n++) { getline ; print } }' filename
```

But doesn't work.
I was thinking of using tail -5 to get only the last 5 lines. (LInes 6 to 10 of only the last match)

You can test it with this:

```
************************** Constrained Symmetrised Forces **************************
 *                                                                                  *
 *                           Cartesian components (eV/A)                            *
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- *
 *                         x                    y                    z              *
 *                                                                                  *
 * O               1     -0.03440             -0.03440              0.00000         *
 * O               2      0.03440              0.03440             -0.00000         *
 * O               3     -0.03440              0.03440             -0.00000         *
 * O               4      0.03440             -0.03440              0.00000         *
 * Ti              1      0.00000              0.00000              0.00000         *
```

I should get the lines that start with O and end with Ti. But throughout the file there are several "constrained"

Comment: Use `sed -n '6,10p' filename`, to print between line 6 and 10 included

Comment: @Zelnes That prints lines 6 to 10 of the file, not after the match.

Comment: Do you only want to match the last `Constrained` in the file, or did you mean "after each match"?

Comment: I only want to match the last one

Comment: That's significantly harder, because you don't know whether it's the last match until you get to the end of the file.

Comment: that's why I thought of getting all the matches, then using tail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is:

```
grep -A10 Constrained file | tail -n 5
```

Comment: Ed you are not fun at all ;-) Brilliant to see how most of us are grepping tacing awking while it is as easy as it can be ;-)

Comment: Just to mention, this will fail if there are no 10 lines after the last "Constrained".

Comment: Yeah a solution that just does what the OP mentioned later in her question (`I should get the lines that start with O and end with Ti.`) would be more robust but I'm assuming the OP would let us know of any rainy day cases to be considered.

Comment: Actually, this always brings me to the question. With awk you can do basically everything related to sed,grep,cat,ack,tr,uniq,... . But when should pipelines be recommended? They are often much more readable.

Comment: Its art rather than science but I tend to use pipelines (or individual other commands) when the result is clearer and simpler than an awk script and I don't expect to have to expand on the code in future and it's not something I want to take on in awk simply for the learning experience. If you gain experience using awk for most of the relatively simple (but still appropriate and non-trivial with existing tools) stuff where you don't REALLY need it you'll find it's then much easier to use awk for the complicated stuff where you do.

Comment: This reads and processes the whole file. (If e. g. the match is in between the last 100 lines in a 10G file, grepping the whole file is significantly slower.)

Comment: Right - as always you start with a simple solution and if performance turns out to be an issue then you work on solving that problem.

Answer (score 2):

One option: reverse the file, find the first match plus 10 lines, re-reverse, take the last 5 lines:

```
tac filename | grep -B10 Constrained -m 1 | tac | tail -n 5
```

Comment: what does the -m1 flag do?

Comment: @Caterina type `man grep` in your terminal or google `grep man page`.

Answer (score 2):

```
tac file | grep "Constrained" -m1 -B10 | tac | tail -n5
```

`tac` reverses the file, so you can find the last match easily using `grep -m1`. Second, you want to process the 10 lines (5 to skip and 5 to print) before ('before', because output is reversed). The second `tac` reverses the output again so you get the original line order and `tail -n5` hides the lines between `Constrained` and the 6. line to print after the match.

Of course, you can do that with a simple `grep`, but this will read and process the whole file and can be significantly slower. `tac` starts reading from the end of file.

```
grep -A10 "Constrained" file | tail -n5
```

With awk (also reading the whole file):

```
awk '/Constrained/{f=NR;b=""};NR>=f+6 && NR<=f+10{b=b ORS $0}END{print b}' file
```

Searches for Constrained, sets the initial line number (`f` to current line) and deletes the buffer (for previous results). Then collects lines into `b` as long as the lines numbers match the region.

Comment: @Caterina naah, same answer as the accepted one, but with more explanations (took 3 minutes to write) :-P I should stop writing explanations.

Comment: no you should not ;-) explanations are more useful.

Comment: This answer is almost correct but I'm not getting the last line with "Ti"

Comment: @Caterina See update. I also added something to consider (`grep | tail` vs. `tac | grep | tac | tail`).

Comment: Just in case, I upvoted your answer :)  But I chose the other one because it was simpler

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of to do that is to read the file twice. The first pass finds the last line number of the match, the second pass prints  6-10 after it.

```
awk 'FNR==NR && /Constrained/ { line=NR }
     FNR!=NR && FNR >= line+6 && FNR <= line+10' filename filename
```

Comment: I guess OP wants to match last `Constrained`

Comment: @anubhava Possible. "last match" could mean the last match in the file, or it could mean the most recent match.

Comment: I meant the last match in the file

Comment: This is printing the match too. I don't really want that line

Comment: Then why do you have `print;` before the `for` loop?

Comment: I removed that from the answer.

Comment: @kvantour Won't that make the condition match during the first pass?

Comment: @kvantour I just tested it. If I remove that, it prints the lines after all matches of `Constrained`, not just the last match in the file.

Comment: If `Constrained` is on lines 2 and 14, it prints lines 8-12 and 20-24. It also prints 20-24 twice, once during the first pass and again during the second pass.

Comment: @Barmar you are correct. I overlooked that condition. `awk '(FNR==NR) && /Constrained/{ line=NR}(FNR==NR){next}(FNR >= line+6 && FNR <= line+10)'` but it is less clean.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the file a single time, but keeping track of a buffer:

```
awk '(c-->0){b[10-c]=$0}
     /Constrained/{c=10}
     END{for(i=6;i<=10;++i) print b[i] }' file
```

**How does this work?**

The array `b` is buffer which always will contain the 10 lines following after a match of the pattern `/Constrained/`. A counter `c` will be used to count down to zero. Every time a match of the pattern is found, it is reset to the maximum value of 10. The program works like this:

1. Read a line (default awk action)
2. Check if the counter `c` is bigger than zero and decrease it by 1 (See [What is the "-->" operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/8344060)). If this condition is met, store the line in the buffer `b`. Since we start counting from 9 (10-1), store it at position *10 − i*. This way the lines after the match are indexed as 1,2,3,...,10.
3. If the pattern `/Constrained/` is matched, reset the counter `c` to 10.
4. Go back to 1 unless you are at the end of the file.
5. If you processed the file, the buffer `b` now contains the last 10 lines after the match. Just print line 6 till 10.

**A couple of cleanups:**

It is not necessarily said that after matching the pattern, you have 10 lines, so you have to make sure the previous buffer is fully erased.

```
$ awk '(c-->0){b[10-c]=$0}
       /Constrained/{c=10; delete b}
       END{for(i=6;i<=10;++i) if (i in b) print b[i] }' file
```

**Parametrised version:**

A parameterised version would allow for large ranges. But imagine you want the 10000 till 10001th line after the match. So the buffer would be really big, for just two lines. So we can correct this as:

```
$ awk '(c-->min) && (c<=max-min){b[max-c]=$0}
       ($0~ere){c=max; delete b}
       END{for(i=min;i<=max;++i) if (i in b) print b[i] }' \
       min=6 max=10 ere="Constrained" file
```

Be advised that `min` has to be bigger than 0.

**Proof of principle:**

```
$ awk '(c-->0) && (c<=max-min){b[max-c]=$0}
       ($0~ere){ c=max; delete b}
       END{for(i=min;i<=max;i++) if(i in b) print b[i] }' \
       min=6 max=10 ere="20" <( seq 1 50 && seq 101 150 )
126
127
128
129
130
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try this one.
-A refers to 10 lines after the match of the word.
-m refers on when to stop reading the file. we dont want to read the whole file. do you?

```
grep -A10 Constrained file | tail -5
```

Comment: Yes she does want (need) to read the whole file because otherwise she won't know where the **last** Constrained occurs. What you posted will print the last 5 lines of the **first** Constrained block which is a much simpler problem than the problem the question is about out.

Comment: gotcha. i didnt red the question correctly. -m1 should not come

Comment: Now your answer's identical to mine (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57043558/1745001) which I posted before you answered.

Comment: when i was updating the query, i noticed you already answered it. good for you.

Comment: I was expecting more of a "oh, I hadn't noticed, I'll delete my duplicate answer" but OK.

Comment: mine is still different because it saves 2 characters in the command compared to yours

Comment: YMMV with that as, [per POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tail.html), `If neither -c nor -n is specified, -n 10 shall be assumed.`. I understand that pre-POSIX tail didn't have -n or -c options and so most modern tails so far continue to support `-<number>` as if you wrote `-n <number>` but I wouldn't rely on it since it is undefined behavior at best (and arguably counter-POSIX since POSIX states that without `-n` or `-c` the command should be treated as `-n 10`).

Comment: exactly. This is still in working state and no plan to remove this option is specified/proposed yet.

Comment: no plan to remove it? It's already been removed from the standard, there's almost certainly versions of tail out there that already don't support it (a quick google for "unix tail error" didn't find that but did find a reference to its corollary `+<number>` being removed from Linux RHEL5), and even in the versions that do still support it it already isn't supported in combination with other arguments (e.g. with GNU tail `seq 10 | tail -f -n 3` outputs 
`8
9
10` as expected while `seq 10 | tail -f -3` outputs `tail: option used in invalid context -- 3`). I'm just saying - YMMV.